# How to fully remove svn.iml file that generate PhpStorm from .idea folder

Tags: git, svn, phpstorm, gitignore

In my projects I'm using BitBucket base on Git control version. My IDE is PhpStorm 2017.

My problem is when I remove `myprojectsvn.im`l file from `.idea` folder after some time I can see that file again.

Why is file always create If I've never used svn? For that file when I switch branch I got error like this:

> Can not loading myprojectsvn.iml module

Comment: Do you see it in your local folder or in your remote repository?

Comment: Yep I was check it my local folder and remove that file from .idea folder and commit that to remote repository.  So I check some branches on remote repository so I see .idea folder. Should I remove .idea from remove repository?

Comment: You should remove it from the remote repository firstly. Then, you should add a `.gitignore` file into your project and add `.idea` and `.iml` files into it. By this way you are saying git not to push that files into your remote repository. You can also add some other folders into `.gitignore` file out etc. Check the following link it will help you I guess.  https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes thanks too much

Comment: Could you accept my answer please :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove it from the remote repository firstly. Then, you should add a .gitignore file to your project and add .idea and .iml files into it. By this way, you are saying git not to push that files into your remote repository. You can also add some other folders into .gitignore file out etc. Check the following link it will help you I guess.

[help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files](http://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)